# No data is showing while associating a workflow

Tags: formsflow.ai

I’m using the latest formsflow.ai v4.0.2. And I made a complete deployment using docker. I’m sure that every component is running in docker. You are provided with two sample forms. When I tried to associate workflow it shows “no data”. How can I solve this?

Comment: This can be because one of your application wouldn't have started properly. Please check the docker logs for api / bpm.

Comment: checked and it seems like everything is up

Comment: Please post your camunda logs here.

Comment: Is forms-flow-bpm up? Check docker container logs

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I just brought the bpm again in docker by pruning the docker system and volume. So the issue was solved

Answer (score 2):

I just brought the bpm again in docker by pruning the docker system and volume. So the issue was solved